# Zeppelin: While running Spark code getting spark-interpreter-0.10.0.jar file not found

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Getting following error while executing spark code through Zeppelin.

```
ERROR deploy.ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/zeppelin/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/spark-interpreter-0.10.0.jar
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/zeppelin/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/spark-interpreter-0.10.0.jar
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:526)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:253)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyRecursive(Utils.scala:726)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyFile(Utils.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:541)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$2.run(DriverRunner.scala:99)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property `deployMode` to client.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for response. I was working with Zeppelin with Spark over YARN cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on setup of Zeppelin 0.10 , Spark 3.x and Yarn. This issue got resolved, please refer the image

[image]